# How can I reference a column from another table without creating a property for it in my TypeORM entity class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

In my current implementation, I have an FinancialAccount entity that has a many-to-one relationship with the User entity. However, I only need to reference the user_id column from the User entity in my FinancialAccount entity, and I don't want to create a property for the User entity in my FinancialAccount class.

Is there a way to achieve this using TypeORM?

```
@Entity()
export class FinancialAccount {
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  user: User;

  @Column({ name: 'user_id' })
  userId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'id',
    unique: true,
  })
  accountId: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'account_name',
  })
  accountName: string;

  @Column('text', {
    name: 'tags',
    array: true,
  })
  tags: string[];

  @CreateDateColumn({
    name: 'created_at',
    type: 'timestamp',
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  public createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    name: 'updated_at',
    type: 'timestamp',
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  public updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({
    name: 'is_deleted',
    nullable: false,
    default: false,
  })
  public isDeleted: boolean;
}
```